# Multiple UIViews pixelated when zooming

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibezierpath, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I have two UIViews (BlueView and RedView) that draw a `UIBeizerPath` (It must be uibeizarpath).

My MainView initializes both views and controls the zoom feature.

I can get the views to zoom, however, when they zoom the UIBeizerPaths are pixelated. I have tried using `[viewname].layer.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] * currentScale;` but that does not work.

Any help wold be greatly appreciated!

Through the magic of Photoshop, here are some illustrations of what I am attempting to accomplish.

**What the View looks like not zoomed:**

[image: Non Zoomed]

**My result of zooming in:**

[image: Bad Zoom]

**The desired result when zooming:**

[image: Desired Zoom]

Any suggestions? Would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

**MainView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import “RedLine.h”
#import “BlueLine.h

@interface MainView : UIViewController {
    CGRect screenRect;

    //ZOOM
    CGFloat zoomScale;
    CGFloat _previousScale;
    CGPoint _originalCenter; 

RedLine * redLine;
BlueLine * blueLine;
}
@end
```

**MainView.m**

```
#import "MainView.h"
#import "BlueLine.h"
#import "RedLine.h"

// ZOOM SCALE
#define MAX_SCALE 4.0
#define MIN_SCALE 1.0


@interface MainView ()

@end

@implementation MainView

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    zoomScale = 1.0;


    //Draw the lines
    blueLine = [[BlueLine alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:blueLine];

    redLine = [[RedLine alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:redLine];



    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(zoomTool:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];

}

#pragma mark - ZOOM 

//ZOOM VIEW
- (void) zoomTool:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"Pinch scale: %f", recognizer.scale);
    if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        _previousScale = zoomScale;
    }

    CGFloat currentScale = MAX(MIN([recognizer scale] * zoomScale, MAX_SCALE), MIN_SCALE);
    CGFloat scaleStep = currentScale / _previousScale;
    [redLine setTransform: CGAffineTransformScale(redLine.transform, scaleStep, scaleStep)];
    redLine.layer.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] * currentScale;
    [blueLine setTransform: CGAffineTransformScale(blueLine.transform, scaleStep, scaleStep)];
    blueLine.layer.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] * currentScale;

    _previousScale = currentScale;

    if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ||
        [recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled ||
        [recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed) {
        // Gesture can fail (or cancelled?) when the notification and the object is dragged simultaneously
        zoomScale = currentScale;
    }


}
@end
```

**BlueLine.m**

```
#import "BlueLine.h"

@implementation BlueLine

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIBezierPath *thisLine = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    [thisLine moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
    [thisLine addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(250, 250)];
    thisLine.lineWidth = 10;
    [[UIColor blueColor] setStroke];
    [thisLine stroke];

}
@end
```

**RedLine.m**

```
#import "RedLine.h"

@implementation RedLine

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIBezierPath *thisLine = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    [thisLine moveToPoint:CGPointMake(300, 300)];
    [thisLine addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 450)];
    thisLine.lineWidth = 10;
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    [thisLine stroke];

}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Transform will just stretch the view,so it gets pixelated instead follow below procedure.

when ever zoom happens call the setNeedsLayout method of your views.And increase the lineWidth by scale times original width.It will draw perfectly.

Add a new public property to your views.And below missing lines.

```
@property CGFloat zoomScale;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
 zoomScale=1.0;
}

-(void)drawRect{
    thisLine.lineWidth = 10*zoomScale;
}
```

so whenever zoom happens ,

```
blueView.zoomScale =zoomScale;
[blueView setNeedsDisplay];
```

**FULL CODE (FOR RED LINE)**

```
- (void) zoomTool:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"Pinch scale: %f", recognizer.scale);
    if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        _previousScale = zoomScale;
    }

    CGFloat currentScale = MAX(MIN([recognizer scale] * zoomScale, MAX_SCALE), MIN_SCALE);
    redLine.scale=currentScale;
    [redLine setNeedsDisplay];
    _previousScale = currentScale;

    if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ||
        [recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled ||
        [recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed) {
        // Gesture can fail (or cancelled?) when the notification and the object is dragged simultaneously
        zoomScale = currentScale;
    }
}
```

**RedLine.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RedLine : UIView
@property CGFloat scale;
@end
```

**RedLine.m**

```
#import "RedLine.h"

@implementation RedLine
@synthesize scale =scale;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        scale=1.0f;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {


    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    CGPoint p1 =CGPointMake(50, 50);
    CGPoint p2 =CGPointMake(300, 300);

    CGFloat offsetX =self.center.x *(scale-1);
    CGFloat offsetY =self.center.y *(scale-1);

    p1.x =p1.x*scale -offsetX;
    p1.y =p1.y*scale -offsetY;

    p2.x =p2.x*scale -offsetX;
    p2.y =p2.y*scale -offsetY;


    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10*scale);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, p1.x, p1.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, p2.x, p2.y);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);

}
@end
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. However, while the lines scale in size, they are still pixelated.

Comment: are you still appling the transform? dont apply the transform now

Comment: Not applying the transfrom, just keeps the UIView the same size while resizing the line.s

Comment: based on zoomScale,just translate (move) those views, and drawRect will draw bigger lines, totally gives a zoom no-pixelated effect.

Comment: Im not sure how you are wanting me to implement that.

Comment: Ok, let me try this out.